# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: flutter, agora.io

After upgrading to `agora_rtc_engine` 5.0.0 I'm experiencing the following build error:

**Command:** `flutter build appbundle`

**Error message:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':agora_rtc_engine:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 31.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.
```

This is the setup in my build gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.MyPackage"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling build tools, upgrading gradle version, but no luck. Anyone experiencing the same issue?

In the meantime I'm downgrading to 4.2.1 as I'm not in need of any new feature, but eventually I'll need to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `targetSDKVersion` to `31`